# PDO connection throwing time out error

Tags: php, pdo, include

I'm having an issue with my PDO connection timing out, it's not in a loop (which is the only time i have seen something time out) just a standard connection and then i run it in a loop later.  the error it is giving is :

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in Connect.php on line 9
```

this is connect.php
[image: connect]

this is essentialy where i am including it
[image: include]

i have also tried require once, and that `print_r` prints:

```
PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) PDO Object ( ) 
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in Connect.php on line 9
```

so obviously there is a connection of some sort and obviously the include is carrying the variable. ALSO i have used this code in other php files and it has worked fine. any ideas from the information given?

line 9 is where `$conn` is set

Comment: disregard root and no password please :)

Comment: If your `print_r` is displaying multiple times, then clearly there is a loop somewhere, even if you didn't intend it. You could try doing a `dump_backtrace()` and seeing where the code is actually coming from?

Comment: Please forget these images, they are unreadable. You can easily paste your code here.

Comment: The point is: it's not worth fooling around with images when you can paste your code here, and it'll even get highlighted.

Comment: @IMSoP youre comment actually answered the issue, i didnt take it into consideration but i was running a loop higher up on the page with the query. if you want to put your comment as the answer i'll except it

Comment: Those colors are beautiful. What is it ?

Comment: @Nick I don't care whether you can read it. I tried to notify you how we do things here on StackOverflow. You know, I'm trying to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Expanded from comment] Since your `print_r()` just below the `include` is running multiple times, it suggests that the whole file/code block is being run multiple times from a loop higher up the code. You could try doing a `dump_backtrace()` and seeing where the code is actually coming from.

The timeout appears to happen in `connect.php` because you are using `include` not `include_once`, so that file is also being re-processed every time the looped code runs.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you executing the same query over and over.
Don't you want to do something like:

```
$stmt = $conn->query($your_query);
while(($result = $stmt->fetch()) !== false){
  // do something
}
```

instead?